# Laptop workstation recommendations

Tags: laptop

> Instead of asking for a comparison of two laptops, list out your requirements, budget, and use case(s) and we will find the best laptop that fits your needs.

Requirement: large data set (>80GB), 17 inch monitor

Use cases: run Matlab, R, Python, SAS for computation

Budget: 2K-3K

Option 1: workstation laptop
One candidate: Dell Inspiron 7500 (one system) has 
OpenCL Score 113610 https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/compute/653552
Geekbench Score 14181 https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/cpu/7357889

Option 2: workstation desktop and remote access

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting up a small headless workstation, which can be even as small as an HTPC but house Ryzen 2700x on a mini-ITX motherboard and using a laptop to connect to it either using Remote Desktop or ssh, since I have a similar setup and it is quite convenient to use.

For example you can build workstation with following components:

ASUS ROG STRIX B450-I GAMING AM4 AMD B450 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.1 HDMI Mini ITX AMD Motherboard:

https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813119143

CORSAIR Vengeance LPX 32GB (2 x 16GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 3200 (PC4 25600) Desktop Memory Model CMK32GX4M2L3200C16:

https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820236315

SAMSUNG 960 EVO M.2 1TB NVMe PCI-Express 3.0 x4 Internal Solid State Drive (SSD) MZ-V6E1T0BW:

https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA12K54C9643

SILVERSTONE SFX Series SST-ST30SF-V2 300W SFX 80 PLUS BRONZE Certified Active PFC Power Supply:

https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817256175

MITXPC MX500 Industrial Fanless Mini-ITX Case w/ WallMount Bracket & VESA Screws:

https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAB944MW9009

And you can use a laptop of your choice, like Asus ZenBook or Lenovo Thinkpad.